# How can I save a JSON string to a dictionary?

Tags: python, json

I have a script that successfully returns a JSON string but I need to convert this string to a format that will work with JSON Server (a fake REST API). The script runs fine and even saves everything in to file. I've tested the JSON at JSONLint and it says that it is valid.

The server expects the format to be:

```
{
  "posts": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
  ],
  "comments": [
    { "id": 1, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 }
  ],
  "profile": { "name": "typicode" }
}
```

My script is currently returning:

```
{"devId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "dps": {"1": false, "109": false, 
"111": false, "110": false, "102": 180, "103": 0, "106": 65, "107": 0, 
"104": 65, "105": 57}}
```

Here is what I am currently using to save the file:

```
with open("temperatures.json", "w") as write_file:
json.dump(data, write_file)
```

What do I need to add to my script so that it will save the JSON as a file in the format expected by JSON Server?

Comment: Those documents are unlike each other not just in syntax but in semantics -- which is to say, they don't contain the same data at all. Note that whitespace that's outside of quotes isn't syntactically significant in JSON -- the document is just as valid (or invalid) with or without it; "pretty printing" is added for human readability, not for machine consumers.

Answer (score 0):

You build the object before encoding it to a JSON string:

```
import json

data = {}
data['key'] = 'value'
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

and your object are not identical try to update it. It will be more clear if you give your temperatures.json output

Answer (score 0):

You can get all keys like this:

```
import json

arr = '[{"a": "111", "b": "222", "c": "333", "d": "444", "e": "555"},{"a": "111", "b": "222", "c": "333", "d": "444", "e": "555"}]'
# convert string to json
j = json.loads(arr)
for idx, el in enumerate(j):
    print(el)
    for key in el:
        print(key)
```

You can create a new json like this:

```
import json
arr = '[{"a": "111", "b": "222", "c": "333", "d": "444", "e": "555"}, {"a": "111", "b": "222", "c": "333", "d": "444", "e": "555"}]'
# your final json
json_dic = {}
# convert string to json
j = json.loads(arr)
for idx, el in enumerate(j):
    print(el)
    print(el['a'])
    # create your new json
    json_dic['id'] = el['a']
    json_dic['title'] = el['b']
    json_dic['author'] = el['c']
    # json.dumps to stringify the json
    print(json.dumps(json_dic))
    for key in el:
        print(key)
```